# How to get the child div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, parent-child

I want to get the child div of main div

```
<div class="test">
<div id="dog"></div>
<div id="cat"></div>
<div id="drig"></div>
</div>
```

​

```
var a= $("div.test #dog");

alert (a);


var b= $("div.test #abc");

alert (b);
```

The problem is both `a` and `b` are returning the `[object object]`. where as there is no child id `abc`

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/8yJNS/

Comment: You question isn't clear. What is "cathup"? What it is you're asking about?

Comment: try with `console.log()` not `alert()`

Comment: @kinakuta its catchup :D
means get that element.

Comment: `console.log()` ?? value is in variable and doesn't matter How I view it .. @thecodeparadox

Comment: JSfiddle is working for me showing ID of div. What you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `[Object object]` is expected from your code as even if no element is found, jQuery will return an empty jQuery object.

If you want to check whether the selector found anything, use `length`:

```
var a = $("div.test #dog");
alert(a.length); // 1 element found

var b = $("div.test #abc");
alert(b.length); // 0 elements found
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yJNS/31/)

Answer (score 2):

You can get id by something as below...

```
var a= $("div.test #dog"); 
 alert (a.id);
```

or

```
   $(a).attr('id');
```